# how do i reference to the swiftmailer from a User entity

Tags: email, symfony, sendmail

I want so send a mail to a user using a method of the entity,
therefore I use the following code

```
use Symfony\Bridge\Swiftmailer;

public function sendMail($subject, $content)
{
    $mailer = Swiftmailer::newInstance();
    $message = \Swift_Message::newInstance()
        ->setSubject($subject)
        ->setFrom('fh-bingen@fh-bingen.de')
        ->setTo($this->getEmail())
        ->setBody($content);
        $mailer->send($message);
    return $this;
}
```

my problem is that it doesn't find Swiftmailer this way, also my first problem was that i could solve this by a simple

```
$this->get("mailer")
```

in a Controller but apparently that doesn't work in the entity (I don't know if there had been some work before for the command because i didn't write it.)

Comment: The Entity is just a simple object, it's not aware of the service container and it's not supposed to perform this kind of task. You should move the email logic to a controller or to another service.

Answer (score 2):

Important: you should not send e-mail from entities. Entity should know nothing about sending e-mails.

To send e-mail you should use `mailer` service (more at http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/email/email.html) and depending on action you want to perform you can do it from controller, command or for example from custom UserManager service.

If only you could give more details, I would suggest a suitable solution.

Comment: Sending the mail outside of an entity was no problem, I don't know why there is a problem with the Entity mailing though.

Comment: To send e-mail you need access to mailer service. I's not a problem to send e-mail from entity if you pass to entity mailer object but it's really bad programming practice.
Better solution is to send e-mail from for example EventListener / EventSubscriber that will listen to events from entity.